# Specify SELECT timeout for SQLITE

Tags: sql, sqlite, timeout

Is it possible to specify the maximum amount of time a SELECT query may take with SQLITE?

The situation would be useful where you have big tables and the users have to possibility to enter free search terms. If the searched for terms is not quickly found then the entire table is scanned which can take a very long time as indices cannot generally be used.

So having SQLITE give up after a few seconds would be useful.

I am using SQLITE via the System.Data.Sqlite and it seemed that SqliteCommand.CommandTimeout would be what I want, but setting this seem to have no effect for some reason. Perhaps I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For a simple select query**, no, there doesn't appear to be a way to set a timeout, or maximum time to execute, on SQLite itself. The only mention of timeout in the documentation is [the busy timeout](http://www.sqlite.org/tclsqlite.html#timeout). So, if you need to limit the maximum amount of time a select query can take, you'll need to wrap your connection with a timeout in the application level, and cancel/close your connection if that timeout is exceeded. How to do that would obviously be application/language specific.

**For a busy timeout** (the timeout before the connection stops waiting for locks to clear) you can do it through [the provided C interface](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/busy_timeout.html), or through the SQLite driver provided to your application.

Comment: Isn't the BUSY handler function in the link only called when a table lock cannot be taken? And not when a query takes a really long time.

Comment: My apologies - I've updated my answer to address non-busy timeouts.

Comment: Thanks! But is it possible to cancel a connection (SqlLiteConnection) when the select operation is still running? I assume this would have to be done from another thread then. Is that safe? Do you call the Close method on the connection object?

Comment: Since it's a read operation on the DB, I don't think it's unsafe in terms of data integrity to just drop it, since you won't be modifying any data. How you cancel the connection is really a matter of what language/driver you're using, so I can't help you too much there. However, in Java, for example, you could use a second thread to monitor the connection, and kill it after a given timeout. Alternatively, you could put the connection in its own thread, and `.interrupt()` it after the timeout.

Comment: However, I'm not sure what would happen to any locks on the DB if you kill a connection. Since SQLite can either have multiple readers OR a single writer at a time, I don't know if the SELECT query will still continue to run in the background, or if dropping the connection will cease its execution. I think you'll just have to run an experiment on your own to see what happens.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured. I suspect that Closing a connection where a query a still running from another thread could cause some trouble if the behaviour is not documented. Most likely the Close would simply block until the select is done if you use an SQLITE build with multithreading support. Or the select continues in the "background" somewhere as you said. Killing the thread outright with something like TerminateThread is a big no-no in my book. At least if I intend to keep the process running afterwards! :)

Comment: Agreed. Maybe the safer way (as opposed to thread killing) would be to actually spawn a small, lightweight process to execute the query. This would have the downside of extra overhead (in creating the process in the first place, esp. in Windows where Processes are "heavier" than say *nix), but I suppose it depends on how badly you need the ability to stop a running query.

Comment: I decided to opt for using smaller db files instead by using day-specific rather than month-specific databases. This gives a natural stop point, can check if it takes too long between querying each file. Also gives better granularity (can delete files for specific days) even if they do require a little more storage.